# Converting IConfigurationSection to IOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

The Options pattern allowed me to create options objects containing values from configuration, as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options

I need the values for one option object within an IDesignTimeDbContextFactory implementation, to be used by EF when creating the models. (The values in that config section will be used for data seeding, and so I added IOptions to the DB Context constructor.)

As I have no access to IServiceCollection (since it's design time - like when running "dotnet ef migrations add", I need to have another way to convert an IConfigurationSection (representing the section I'm interested in) to my custom Options class.

May I know how I can do this without dependency injection?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the [`Bind(Configuration, object)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_) extension method to perform manual binding of any `object`. Here's an example:

```
var myCustomOptions = new MyCustomOptions();
myConfigurationSection.Bind(myCustomOptions);

// Use myCustomOptions directly.
```

To wrap this in an `IOptions<T>`, use [`Options.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.create?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Options_Options_Create__1___0_):

```
IOptions<MyCustomOptions> myOptions = Options.Create(myCustomOptions);
```

Answer (score 5):

you can also use

```
config.Get<MyCustomOptions>()
```

This is an extension method from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration namespace. I see it in Assembly Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=3.1.9.0. Perhaps, it exists in earlier versions also. That would give you the Settings object itself. then you can wrap it into IOptions as Krik showed in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you need [Bind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.configuration.configurationbinder.bind?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_ConfigurationBinder_Bind_Microsoft_Extensions_Configuration_IConfiguration_System_Object_) method:

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()...Build();
var myOptions = new MyOptions();
config.GetSection("MyOptions").Bind(myOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

**ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions** makes this work in the SoapCore

The part from my application worked out like that:

```
            services.AddSingleton<IRESAdapterService>(new RESAdapterService(
                new XController(
                    services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<IOptions<XApiSettingsFromJsonClass>>(),
                    _xLogger
                    )));
```

Also usable in the integrity unittests