# How to create an IOptions<T> from a custom instance of T (not via DI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I would like to pass a value to an `IOptions<T>` parameter.

I can only find examples of using `IOptions<T>` with configuration, but I need to define a **custom value** when invoking a method.

Comment: Implement the interface into a concrete class and pass this as a parameter...? Alternatively if code allows and options isn't required you may be able to pass a null.

Comment: @Adriani6 it fails if I pass null. it's in a constructor and I'm invoking base so I can't really create new objects. I'll update the question with more code

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53166201/converting-iconfigurationsection-to-ioptions/53168921#53168921) help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOptions Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150178/ioptions-injection)

Comment: @Hasan please read the question. I can only find examples of IOptions with configuration and injection. that's NOT what I was looking for

Answer (score 15):

I am assuming that you are asking how to create a custom `IOptions<TOptionClass>` value where you specify the instance of `T` to be used. Here is how you can do that:

Let's assume you have a class called `IdentityOptions` as in your example.

First create an instance of it:

```
var optionsInstance = new IdentityOptions();
// ... set properties on it as needed
```

Then convert it into an Option-container:

```
IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionParameter = Options.Create(optionsInstance);
```

See [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.options.create?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_Extensions_Options_Options_Create__1___0_).

**Update:** I was a few seconds slower than the OP's own solution. Let me add **a possible extension-method solution** so this answer still has some added value (not tested):

```
public static IOptions<TOptions> AsIOption<TOptions>(this TOptions optionInstance) where TOptions : class, new()
{
    return Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(optionInstance);
}
```

Which then you can use as `optionInstance.AsIOption()`. I'm not sure if it's worth the effort (I don't like to pollute the `Object` class if not necessary), but certainly possible, and might get useful if you use this technique at many different places.

Answer (score -1):

My solution:

```
public LCSignInManager(UserManager<Profile> userManager, IdentityDbContext db, IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<Profile> claimsFactory, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor = null) : base(userManager, contextAccessor, claimsFactory, optionsAccessor, new LoggerFactory().CreateLogger<LCSignInManager>(), (IAuthenticationSchemeProvider)new AuthenticationSchemeProvider(GetOption()).GetDefaultAuthenticateSchemeAsync().Result)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
    this.DbContext = db;
}

private static IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> GetOption()
{
    var settings = new AuthenticationOptions
        {

        };

    IOptions<AuthenticationOptions> result = Microsoft.Extensions.Options.Options.Create(settings);

    return result;
}
```